# Refresh Newsstand app and badge icon

Tags: ios

I have created a magazine app enabled for the Newsstand. The problem is, the app only refreshes/fetches a new issue when the reader launches the app.

I want my app to check for new issues on a daily basis and update the app's shelf as soon as it finds a new issue. I don't want the app to automatically download the new issue, just to update the shelf and the Newsstand shelf cover and badge the Newsstand icon, letting the reader know there's a new magazine issue available.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you thought about using push notifications? Server not local. That way you can send a message/badge icon to everyone without the need to open up the app to get notified. I know there are free services out there.

Comment: Yes, I've installed Parse, but unfortunately only message notifications are working. The icon is not badged. There must be some lines of code interfering, but I can't quite figure out which ones. However, Parse is not automatically updating the Newsstand icon, unless the user launches the app and the new issue is fetched.